# How to turn off CodeLens (reference counts above methods) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I set the visual studio 2022 so that it does not show the references for methods and classes?

Change some settings?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean the annotation above each class/property/method declaration ("2 References"), this is done by the CodeLens feature.

Tools > Options ... search for "CodeLens" (should at least show a section under Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens). Adjust to taste, perhaps turning the feature off entirely.

Comment: Or just right click on the CodeLens text and navigate to options from there.

Comment: Nice! I've left-clicked on those references a million times... never once thought to right-click on them.

Comment: "Show C# and Visual Basic References" is grayed out (and checked).

Comment: @JayBuckman It's like that for me too. I think you need to turn the feature off entirely in that case.